# How to disable right click in a QTreeWidget in PyQt?

Tags: qt, events, pyqt, mouse, qtreewidget

I have a QTreeWidget where I want to disable right click on the item. Currently I am using `itemClicked` signal to detect clicks on children of the treeWidget, but I only want to do something when the user left clicks an item and do nothing on right click. Both left and right clicks are getting detected right now and I am not able to differentiate between the two.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reimplement the treewidget's [mouse release event](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseReleaseEvent):

```
class TreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):    
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() != QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            super(TreeWidget, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)
```

or install an [event-filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) on the treewidget's viewport:

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget(self)
        self.tree.viewport().installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonRelease and
            event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton and
            source is self.tree.viewport()):
            return True
        return super(Window, self).eventFilter(source, event)
```

Comment: Is `ItemClicked` really triggered from the `MouseReleaseEvent`?

Comment: @Mailerdaimon. Ultimately, yes. It's emitted via the `clicked` signal, which comes from the `mouseReleaseEvent` of `QAbstractItemView`. The equivalent code using `mousePressEvent`, won't work correctly. To be specific, it won't eat right-clicks on selected items. (It also changes the selection behaviour when right-clicking, if that matters).

Answer (score 2):

You can override the MouseEvent:

```
void MyTreeWidget::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
   event->accept();
}
```

To preserve the usual behaviour of the Widget you have to call the base class for all Buttons you want to work.

```
void MyTreeWidget::mousePressEvent ( QMouseEvent * event )
{
   if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
       event->accept(); // accept event and do nothing
   else:
       QTreeView::mousePressEvent(event)
}
```

**EDIT:**

Have just noticed that you are working with Python: the mechanics are the same so the above Example should work if translated to Python.

Answer (score 0):

If I understad you correctly you want to disable selection .
I'm not familiar to PyQT but in C++ you should write code like this:

```
yourtreeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);
```

In this case items would not get selected but you still will see focus rectangle around them. To fix this you can set your widget to not accept focus by calling:

```
yourtreeView->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Comment: I don't want to disable selection. Just the selection on right click. I still want the item to be selected on left click.